# How to reduce the blank space in report?

Tags: jasper-reports

This is my template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report_viwe_2" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="3cb87247-a775-45d7-b09b-4211897bff60">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM team]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="team_teamno" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="team_teamlead" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="team_teammem1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="team_teammem2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="team_teamlead">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teamlead}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bff92bff-1492-496c-b0e5-5e5e38f341e5" x="24" y="33" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teamno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="fa26359e-2fc7-4fdf-a972-9265832c77ac" x="162" y="33" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teamlead}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c425bb55-97cb-4949-8926-3159f109aaa8" x="284" y="33" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teammem1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="9dda41b1-e0f1-403d-ae59-ee7fe15889a3" x="414" y="33" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teammem2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d6efe743-2133-45da-82ba-f8eb56e82c9e" x="39" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teamno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d1b79bae-55ae-47e3-9b16-403af876b6d0" x="185" y="9" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teamlead}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="a653ec3b-4ce4-4871-b784-a7fa9878293a" x="297" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teammem1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c4bb9aa3-3dc2-4db0-a13b-31d43b1972d3" x="447" y="12" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{team_teammem2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I am just trying to print the JasperReports' report on web page using php.

The problem is while printing on web page, the first page will be blank, in next page it will display the data. I was reducing the band height. but yet there is a extra page appear.

Comment: So how were you printing it using PHP? I assume you had some PHP code to do so. Where is it?

Comment: @Mark Baker:thanks to reply this post and i posted my php code..!!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your empty bands. You have `title`, `pageHeader` and `columnHeader` bands that have declared heights but are unused. These bands will appear before your detail band. Delete them completely or at least set their heights to zero.

You also have `background`, `columnFooter`, `pageFooter` and `summary` bands that are empty and could be deleted too.